# After cancel a notification, cannot renotify a notification with the same ID again. Why?

Tags: android, notifications

I'm developing on Android Studio. I have a service that generates a notification that is updated when a change is detected in the network (WiFi, 3G). The service is controlled by a switch and generates notifications that cannot be deleted by the user.
When I stop the service, I use cancel(id) to remove the notification.
The problem is that when I try to activate the service again, notifications are not generated . Is there any way to fix this? 
These are the lines of code where I generate a notification:
PD. No Exception is generated

EDIT

I tried to create a notification with another id but it doesn't work.

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {

        WifiManager wifimanager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);

        //Datos
        try {
            if(wifimanager.isWifiEnabled() && values[0].equalsIgnoreCase("false") && values[1].equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                NotificationManager manager;
                Notification myNotication;
                manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                Intent notificacionIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), Servicio.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, notificacionIntent, 0);
                Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
                builder.setTicker("Wifi-3G");
                builder.setContentTitle("Wifi-3G Notification");
                builder.setContentText(getString(R.string.conectado_wifi));
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.logo_agus_android);
                builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                builder.setOngoing(true);
                //builder.setAutoCancel(true);
                myNotication = builder.build();
                manager.notify(11, myNotication);
            }
```

Here I cancel the service:

```
swt.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(Servicio.this);
            auxS = Boolean.toString(isChecked);
            Preferencia pref = new Preferencia(2,"Servicio", auxS);
            db.updatePrefe(pref);
            if (isChecked){
                startService(new Intent(Servicio.this, MyService.class));
                Notificacion noti = new Notificacion(1, 11, "Wifi-3G Notification", "Estás conectado a la red a través de WiFi", "Servicio.class");
                db.addNotificacion(noti);
            }
            else {
                stopService(new Intent(Servicio.this, MyService.class));
                Notificacion noti = new Notificacion(1, 11, "Wifi-3G Notification", "Estás conectado a la red a través de WiFi", "Servicio.class");
                db.deleteNotificacion(noti);
            }
        }
    });
```

I cancel the notification in onDestroy() method:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.servicio_destruido, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    pref=new Preferencia(3,"EstadoServ","false");
    db.updatePrefe(pref);
    NotificationManager  manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.cancel(11);
    Conexiones.cancel(true);
}
```

I'm not an English speaking and this is my first question, sorry about that. If you need more information about my code, do not hesitate to ask me.

Comment: try to call super.onDestroy() after executing your code. @Victor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve, the problem was that the onCancelled() method was not being used.

Answer (score -1):

You can update the notification, but you cant use the same notification id as long as the app in memory.

Comment: For some reason, all the notifications are being blocked, including notifications with different ID.

Comment: This happens if the user id which was used for playstore has not alowed notifications from app. Use OAuth to ask user to allow notifications.